# How to set "user cannot change password" AD attribute

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

I'm trying to figure out how to set the "User cannot change password" attribute of AD using VB.NET.

I was originally hoping to use the UserAccountControl Flags found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144 but I realized you cannot set the `PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` flag like one would expect.  This lead me to this posting [Preventing an Active Directory user from changing his/her password using DirectoryServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191969/preventing-an-active-directory-user-from-changing-his-her-password-using-directo) but I cannot get the saving working.

Here's the code I have right now.

```
        Dim domainContext As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
        Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "user5")
        user.UserCannotChangePassword = True
        user.Save(domainContext)
```

Every time I try to do a save on this I get an InvalidOperationException.  The documentation for this isn't too helpful either: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335863.aspx

What's strange to me is that if I set a different attribute of that UserPrincipal object, like the SamAccountName, saving works fine, but once I introduce that `UserCannotChangePassword` attribute, saving fails.

I've verified that the user I am using to perform this action has proper privileges, but I'm not to sure where to go from here...  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  I was hoping to use this new UserPrincipal class because it makes all of my work for AD management much easier.  I can (in theory) change attributes in 3 lines of code rather than 20.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a DirectoryServicesCOMException with a description of "A constraint violation occurred."... Not too helpful, I know. In the msdn link in my original post, I saw that this exception (InvalidOperationException) can occur if the principal has not yet been associated with the PrincipalContext, OR the principal cannot be inserted in the store... I am clearly associated with the PrincipalContext because I can save other attributes, but I have no clue what "cannot be inserted in the store" means, and there's very little help out there.

Comment: Just tried both of the VB.NET solutions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180915(v=vs.90).aspx and both resulted in constraint violations.  I was wondering whether or not something was messed up with my DirectoryEntry object, but I verified that was working fine when I could save other attributes in my first example... I double-checked permissions and the account that is executing the code indeed has permission to change this attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an old school way to do this, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @juergen d.  Guess I'll have to settle.

```
        Dim objThisUser As IADs
        Dim intUserFlags As Integer

        ' Bind to the user object with the current credentials.
        objThisUser = GetObject("WinNT://" + gstrDomain + "/" + "user5")

        intUserFlags = objThisUser.Get("userFlags")

        'can't change
        intUserFlags = intUserFlags Or ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE

        ' Modify the userFlags property.
        objThisUser.Put("userFlags", intUserFlags)

        ' Commit the changes
        objThisUser.SetInfo()
```

I was close the whole time to having a perfect solution, but just couldn't get the saving to work.  This works fine I guess.  Using this just means a few more lines of code, and a bit less adaptability.